# How to persist Spring Security Authentication with Angular front-end

Tags: java, angular, spring-security

After the first comments on my question, I modified my Spring Security implementation and I managed to login and reach test endpoint with Postman. However, when Angular calls the same endpoint after successful login, the call fails and the authentication is gone, the call is anonymous according to logs.

Here is the new Security Config configure method:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());
}
```

Here is the getAuthenticationFilter method:

```java
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager);
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new HttpStatusReturningAuthenticationFailureHandler());

    return filter;
}
```

and my secured endpoint:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<ExcelUploadResponse> test() {
    LOGGER.info("In test");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ExcelUploadResponse("Test OK!"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

With Postman, the login responds 200 OK and the test endpoint is reached and returns "test OK!".

Postman requests:

`POST http://localhost:8080/api/login` (with user credentials as body)
Response:
Status 200 OK (with Cookie: JSESSIONID D3BBCC0BF4134909C83FAE45C72BC5F7 localhost /annuaire Session true false)

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/test`
Response:
Status 200 OK (with "Test OK!" as body and with same Cookie)

With Angular, the login responds with 200 OK, but the next GET calls to test endpoint fails with 403 Forbidden and the debug logs of Spring Security are as below:

```
2023-01-05 10:25:15.796 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /excel/test
2023-01-05 10:25:15.796 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.798 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.802 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /excel/test] with attributes [fullyAuthenticated]
2023-01-05 10:25:15.808 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-01-05 10:25:15.808 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.808 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.808 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-01-05 10:25:15.811 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-01-05 10:25:15.811 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.811 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.811 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2023-01-05 10:25:15.862 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.865 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-05 10:25:15.865 DEBUG 6516 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

The only difference I notice with the GET request is the JSESSIONID present in the Cookie key/value of the headers for Postman, but not present in the request headers of Angular.

I have searched for this difference and added as suggested an HttpInterceptor in Angular:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authRequest = req.clone({
          withCredentials: true
        });
        return next.handle(authRequest);
      }
}
```

If I understood wall, this HttpInterceptor with `withCredentials: true` is supposed to solve the cookie missing issue by intercepting all the requests made and adding the cookie to them.

But it's not working and I still have an error 403 when trying to reach the test endpoint after having logged in in Angular.

Comment: You can't disable CORS in your application. It is a browser feature, you have to disable it in your browser. `.cors().disable()` means that CORS is not allowing any Cross Origin Request.

Comment: Log is clear: *Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext*. You are not logged in. You are anonymous.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own custom login? Spring Security has a lot of built-in authentications like form login, basic auth, OAuth2 and JWT.

Comment: @dur Thank you for your comments, it helps me a lot. As I have explained it is the first time I am using Spring Security, so I made a lot of errors in the implementation. I didn't used login form and basic auth as I would like to use my login component in Angular Frontend. And indeed, I am not logged in. I am tryning a new implementation that works with Postman, but failed in Angular. I will edit my question with new implementation as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to fix my issue.

The problem was that Spring Security responds with a cookie with key `jsessionid` and a random value when hitting `/login` endpoint and this cookie was sent back with same value by Postman when hitting the secured endpoint to authorize the request, but in Angular frontend, despite the fact that I added the HttpInterceptor with `whithCredentials: true`, the cookie was filtered out in the response with info message stating that the path of the secure cookie didn't match the exact request url.

I have added to the `application.properties` the line:

`server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/`

and the cookie was sent back by Angular successfully to authorize my requests to the secured endpoint.